# How to write contents of a JTable to a txt file

Tags: swing

I wonder if anyone could kindly tell me how to write the contents of a JTable to a .txt file. I have a basic knowledge of java and know about FileReaders etc, but just don't know how to do something as complicated as this. Thanks-please could you also provide a bit of sample code. Thanks again

Comment: Here's something that might be of some help: http://www.coderanch.com/t/275285/Streams/java/Readind-Writing-Contents-JTable-txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like the below. I wrote the below off the top of my head but I think it is right.

Regards,

Guido

```
TableModel model = table.getTableModel();

for( int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++ )
{
   for( int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); j++ )
   {
   //Create your File Writer
   fileWriter.write( model.getValueAt( i, j );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, a year on and I'm slightly(only slightly) better at Java than I was when I asked the question. Obviously you'd have to create the fileWriter somewhere, but the basic idea looks right.  Thank you!